# How to pause and play video on vlcj?

Tags: java, vlcj

Playing a video using `vlcj` on java swing works, but pausing with `jbutton` and `paused()`, doesn't.

```
package tutorial;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent;

public class Tutorial {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My First Media Player");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
        panel.add(mediaPlayerComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        mediaPlayerComponent.mediaPlayer().media().play("C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\Rex Orange County.mp4");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// toggle pause
mediaPlayerComponent.mediaPlayer().controls().pause(); 

// explicitly set paused
mediaPlayerComponent.mediaPlayer().controls().setPause(true);

// play
mediaPlayerComponent.mediaPlayer().controls().play()
```